# Create a toggle between two actions in IFTTT

Tags: aws-lambda, iot, alexa-skills-kit, ifttt, amazon-echo

I have a simple device ([Nordic Thingy 52](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Nordic-Thingy-52)) with a push button which can trigger the [Maker Webhooks](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) service in order to pass an event (`button_press`), which I am currently using to then trigger the Smart Life service's "Turn Off" or "Turn On" action.

The problem is that, since I can only pass the one event (`button_press`), I have to choose whether that event triggers either "Turn Off" or "Turn On". But what I want is to add some logic to say, "If the previous request was to turn off the Smart Life device, make the next one turn on the smart life device."

Wasn't sure how to do this. An AWS Lambda function? Chaining some other preexisting service? A filter that utilizes local storage or somehow handles state logic?

Any pointers for where to start searching would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this with a service called [apilio](http://www.apilio.io/).

Process:

Head to apilio.io and register for an account.

- Enter your IFTTT token in your user profile page.
- Go to Boolean Variables and enter a variable called `bln_light_on`. Set its default value to `false`
- Go to `Conditons > New Condition for Boolean`. Call it `cnd_light_on`.
- Under variable select `bln_light_on` with a required state of `True`.
- Under `name` create a name of `lgc_light_on` with conditon `cnd_light_on`, with Condition Linking set to `Simple AND`
- Under `Action Chains > Actions for Positive Result` enter `button_on`
- Under Action Chains > Actions for Negative Result enter button_off
- Under `Execution Mode` select `Immediate`. Under `Advanced Options > Automatic Evaluation` select `Evaluate this logicblock when any connected variable changes`.
  Now, in IFTTT, create a `New Applet > Web Hooks > If maker Event "button_press"`, then > `Web Hooks > make a web request`
  In the URL field you’ll enter the Toggle URL from the `bln_light_on` Boolean Variable you set up in Apilio. You can see this by clicking `Boolean Variables > bln_light_on > show` from the menu. 
  Lastly, in the Nordic Thingy Web App, send the event `button_press`

Comment: Note that apilio is not a free service; it's currently $11.40/yr for 3 logic blocks or $41 for 75.  You can have one free logic block but you'd have to renew every 2 months.